# Create an example that fails if UNICODE_CASE is turned off, but matches when turned on

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I have tried many variations, I even tried explicitly turning off `UNICODE_CASE`, but whenever I use `CASE_INSENSITIVE` it matches.

```
    String regex = "(?-u)\u004d"; // M
    String text = "\u006d"; // m
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex,
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE
            //   |Pattern.UNICODE_CASE
    );
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Match!");
        return;
    }
    fail("No match");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need characters that not belong to US-ASCII, for example:

```
String regex = "\u00E0"; // à
String text = "\u00C0"; // À
```

It only matches when you turn on `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE`